# How to use GridView or GridLayout?

Tags: java, android, gridview, grid-layout

I'm creating a seat selection screen but I'm confused, how can I achieve this view. I want to access all selected seats into one single Java file. Plz, help me[image]

EDIT: I've tried this code but with this code, I'm not able to create a view like this into single gridview. Now I'm using 2 separate gridviews for that and two Java files with the separate adapter with them.

Seat_Select.java

```
 public class Seat_Select extends AppCompatActivity {
GridView androidgridview;

int[] image = {
        R.drawable.rect_select, R.drawable.rect_select,
        R.drawable.rect_select, R.drawable.rect_select,
        R.drawable.rect_select, R.drawable.rect_select,
        R.drawable.rect_select, R.drawable.rect_select,
        R.drawable.rect_select, R.drawable.rect_select,

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seat__select);

    androidgridview = findViewById(R.id.grid);
    SeatAdapter seatAdapter=new SeatAdapter(Seat_Select.this,image);
    androidgridview.setAdapter(seatAdapter);

    androidgridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Grid Item " + (position + 1) + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}
```

SeatAdapter.java

```
public class SeatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
int image[];

public SeatAdapter(Context context,int[] image) {
    this.context = context;
    this.image=image;
    layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater.from(context));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid2col,null);
    ImageView imageView= convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
    imageView.setImageResource(image[position]);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

grid2col.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp">
</ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_seat_select.xml

```
     <RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="390dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:columnWidth="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
            />
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid2"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:numColumns="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:gravity="center">

        </GridView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: I've updated my question @Dumbo

Answer (score 1):

Please check [SeatBookingRecylerView](https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/SeatBookingRecyclerView). This example has full source code. It may be helpful for you. This is using `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

**GridView**

GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. The grid items are automatically inserted to the layout using a ListAdapter. you can GridView in your layout file like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="80dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="16dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
 />
```

**GridLayout**

Grid layout is mainly used to align its child views in cells which are the horizontal and vertical intercepts of an invisible line. Each view child is place in a cell and the cells are numbered with the horizontal and vertical indexes.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Space />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="@string/button_name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="@string/button_name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="@string/button_name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:text="@string/button_name" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="@string/button_name" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: so how to achieve view displayed in the image, when I use ** vertical & horizontal spacing** , it applies to all columns but I don't want that

Comment: If you are getting items from webservice then use GridView and create custom adapter to achieve this OR if you want to create static UI then use GridLayout.

Comment: Yes, Sir but my problem is that, with GridView how I can achieve structure displayed above. Please help me with that.